# How to add a carriage return to a newline in C# but only if not already present?

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have a string str that is full of \n characters. How do I add the carriage return character \r before every \n character, but only if the \r character is not already there? I don't want to accidentally have \r\r\n anywhere in the string.

Comment: Why not remove all \r and then replace \n by \r\n? Just a quick thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
string input = "hello world!\nGoodbye to you\r\nAnd goodnight\n";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<!\r)\n", "\r\n");
```

The idea is to use a negative lookbehind which asserts that what precedes the `\n` newline is *not* a `\r` character.  In that case, we replace `\n` with `\r\n\`.

Comment: The simple regex ` "\r?\n"` also works. There is virtually no cost in doing an extra substitution.